# React lazy import from cdn

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, lazy-loading

I'm following this guide to lazy load using React Router and Suspense:

https://itnext.io/async-react-using-react-router-suspense-a86ade1176dc

and this is the code I have so far:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePage = (
  lazy(() => (
    import('./pages/HomePage')
  ))
);

const BookingsPage = (
  lazy(() => (
    import('./pages/BookingsPage')
  ))
);

const LoadingMessage = () => (
  <div>I'm loading...</div>
);

class AppProviders extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/bookings">Bookings</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/bookings" component={BookingsPage} />
              </Switch>
            </Suspense>
          </div>
        </Router>
  }
};

export default AppProviders;
```

Code is splitted as expected, but the problem is that the page (html) and the js files are hosted in different subdomains, for example:

- page: http://**www**.myweb.com/
- js files: http://**cdn**.myweb.com/

When page loads it requests the base js file from the cdn:

- http://**cdn**.myweb.com/js/main.js

but then main.js requests the other chunks from www.myweb.com:

- http://**www**.myweb.com/js/1.js
- http://**www**.myweb.com/js/2.js

which return 404.

Is there a way to tell React lazy to request the files from a different subdomain (in this case it would be '**cdn.myweb.com**' instead of '**www.myweb.com**', where html page is hosted).

May thanks in advance and excuse me for my bad English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is in webpack configuration: **output.publicPath**

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath:

> This is an important option when using on-demand-loading or ***loading external resources*** like images, files, etc. If an incorrect value is specified you'll receive 404 errors while loading these resources.

An example is provided in the same page, too:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
    publicPath: 'https://cdn.example.com/assets/'
  }
};
```